# Power BI/DAX: Clustered column chart based on measure split by another variable

Tags: powerbi, dax

Power BI users.

I have a measure that equals 285, but I need it split into 5 categories by # of calls.
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or more

When I use the measures and variables in a visual table they give me the correct answers, please see picture below. However, I need to make a clustered column chart, where the 5 mentioned categories are on the x-axis and the count of calls on the y-axis.

So it should give me 4, 5, 33, 54, 38

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRikQ.png)

I cannot make tables only measures so with my limited Power BI knowledge this has been hauting me for a week now...

Any ideas?

I tried to make measures with # of calls and count of calls by names because if I do not use names in measures the measure of # of calls just gives me the total (285).

Comment: hi, how you got 5 tables, with filters or any other steps please let me know more information.

Comment: Hey,
I made 5 Dashboard tables under the report function in Power BI. From there, I am able to use my measure for calls and filter it on the "names" so I get the total amount of calls per person. 
The problem I am facing is not being able to use the measure for a clustered column chart, because the measure itself equals 285, where I need it to be "split" onto each person and then group them under the # of calls each person has; 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or more.
Hope this helps!

Comment: yes we need the filter page information to create new measures plus assist table for your aim. send me pbix file or give me these filter pages to do these steps.

Comment: I don't think I can send you the file, as it is connected to a live service. What do you mean by giving you the filter pages? 
Sorry, I am quite unexperienced in Power BI.

Comment: because currently [count of calls] you use filter function so the numbers of " 4, 5, 33, 54, 38" do not come from calculation actually. the first step is to calculate these 5 measures and then name them, so you can get the table with columns and measures.

Comment: pbix file can open without datasource. just send me the pbix is fine, or else i am afraid can not help you.

Comment: This is work related and not sure if I could share the files. If it wouldn't be too much trouble, can you explain how you would make the 5 measures?

Comment: i am afraid it has many trouble. then you can create a demo i will make it for you.